# Sending post request windows phone 8

Tags: c#, php

C# code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var dataToPost = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("param1=value1&param2=value2");
    var result = client.UploadData("http://example.com", "POST", dataToPost);

}
```

There are no .Default method and .GetBytes method for Encoding. 
how can i send post like this on windows phone 8.

Comment: Would [UploadValuesAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144246.aspx) work?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no...